# Find and replace symbols with regex python

Tags: python, regex, replace, match

I have such sample:

```
sample = 'TEXT/xx_271802_1A'
p = re.compile("(/[a-z]{2})")
print p.match(sample)
```

in position of xx may be  any from [a-z] in quantity of 2:

```
TEXT/qq_271802_1A  TEXT/sg_271802_1A  TEXT/ut_271802_1A
```

How can I find this xx and f.e. replace it with 'WW':

```
TEXT/WW_271802_1A  TEXT/WW_271802_1A  TEXT/WW_271802_1A
```

my code returns `None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sample = 'TEXT/xx_271802_1A'
p = re.compile("(/[a-z]{2})")
print p.search(sample).group()
```

Your code return `None` as you are using `match` which matches from `start`.You need `search` or `findall` as you are finding anywhere in string and not at start.

For replacement use

```
re.sub(r'(?<=/)[a-z]{2}','WW',sample)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following Regular expression :

```
>>> sample = 'TEXT/xx_271802_1A'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'([a-z])\1',sample)
['x']
>>> re.sub(r'([a-z])\1','WW',sample)
'TEXT/WW_271802_1A'
>>> sample = 'TEXT/WW_271802_1A TEXT/WW_271802_1A TEXT/WW_271802_1A'
>>> re.sub(r'([a-z])\1','WW',sample)
'TEXT/WW_271802_1A TEXT/WW_271802_1A TEXT/WW_271802_1A'
```

The RegEx `([a-z])\1` searches for 1 letter and then matches it if it repeats immediately.

Comment: here are samples for input TEXT/qq_202_1A TEXT/sg_27_1 TEXT/ut_2718

Comment: Guess you should use `[a-z]{2}` if letter does not repeat it might fail

Comment: @vks Aw! Now that you've answered (without demo), It is not worthwhile to change my answer! :) (Just upvote yours and leave :) )

Comment: @goquartzquartz That would return `'TEXT/WW_202_1A TEXT/sg_27_1 TEXT/ut_2718'`

Answer (score 1):

you only need to do this:

```
sample = re.sub(r'(?<=/)[a-z]{2}', 'WW', sample)
```

No need to check the string before with match. `re.sub` makes the replacement when the pattern is found.

`(?<=..)` is a lookbehind assertion and means *preceded by*, it's only a check and is not part of the match result. So `/` is not replaced.

In the same way, you can add a lookahead `(?=_)` *(followed by)* at the end of the pattern, if you want to check if there is the underscore.